# delays just after bootup on CentOS7.5

Tags: linux, centos7, gnome

I'm using CentOS 7.5.1804.
Right after booting-up, the operating system delays.
For example, when I try to write "python" in a terminal, 
first I write "pyt" and press .
I have to wait a few seconds for the OS to interpolate to "python".
This phenomenon occurs just after booting-up.
After a few days later, this phenomenon goes away.
Does anyone know a clue to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The bit when you press pyt-"tab" is part of **bash-completion** package as the command completion happens after you typed the full command. So the cause has to be investigated starting with bash. My educated guess is that some process or I/O is keeping the system busy.

You can start with some generic system information tools as soon as the system start:

- `uptime` to see the system load
- `vmstat -n 1` to check the status of the CPU
- `ps aux` to check running processes
- `iotop` to check for I/O
- `systemctl list-jobs` to show running jobs in systemd

and based on the result of them perform deeper analysis.

Another thing might be the access to the disk slowing down the systemt at startup. Where is the machine running?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about fixing — there are all kinds of things that could go cause delays. But I can offer a few tips to investigate.

The first step to investigate is to run `set -x` to get a trace of the commands that the shell executes to generate the completions. Watch where it pauses.

do you have the issue with different auto-completion? if its only python you can time the execution of your command

```
time python
```

you can watch if you have some problems at launch with redirect standar output and error to a file.

```
strace python 2>&1 launch.log
```

take a strace at boot and one later then you can check if there is difference between:

```
diff -u delays.log delays2.log | grep ^+
```

hope it can help.